# What is CSS for paper 8.5x11?

Tags: html, css

I want to set css for print html in paper 8.5x11.
 There are two codes.

```
body {
     width: 7.5in;
     padding: 0.5in;
 }
 table.example {
 width: 90%;
 }
```

Or

```
 <style type="text/css">
  .page {
   height: 900px;  /* You'll need to play with this value */
   width: 670px;
   page-break-after: always; /* Always insert page break after this element */
  page-break-inside: avoid; /* Please don't break my page content up browser */
   }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="page">
      <table>
       blah
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

Which one is right?

Comment: Take a look at this [LINK](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

Comment: @Eric, it is too fancy. I just want a simple css for size.

Comment: Why do you need to set your page to a specific size? An ordinary print css file with the right elements removed/restyled is more than good enough.

Comment: I would like to print the resulting HTML compatible/formatted for 8.5x11 paper.

Comment: Why are you asking us which one is right? Can't you just try printing? If you don't have a printer, why don't you try a virtual one? Why are you going to assume you will do the right thing?

Comment: Because I don't know how many pixels are equal to 8.5 inches, test is a stupid method.

Comment: Testing isn't 'stupid'. It's how most people learn. A correct print.css file will format your page to any size paper. You just need to make sure you don't use fixed widths wherever possible and rely on padding/margins to space your content out.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to achieve this would be to use a 'media query'

Insert all declarations for printing at the end of your main style sheet, and enclose them with this distinct rule: `@media print { … }`

1. Include all screen styles in the separate `@media screen {…}` rule;
2. Omit the media type for the condensed style sheet: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>`

[Source](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

Comment: Should add the part about the `@media print`

Comment: I still can't follow u. Do you mind putting the entire code?

Comment: It is specific to your code, read through the tutorial linked 'Source' and give it a shot.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display.